# android how to simulate action bar button click

Tags: java, android

How to simulate click on one of buttons in action bar (ex. after receiving some event in app)?

I was sure that something like that will work:

```
tmpButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.button3);
tmpButton.performClick();
```

Unfortunately I get NullPointerException. It's probably related with the fact that button3 is not a classic button but an item in the action bar menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_import"
    android:title="bla bla"/>
```

How to solve that?

Comment: Are you simulating the button click to perform the function or to show the user visually the pressing of the button?

Comment: In order to show visually part of the menu. I have action bar, two buttons (items in the bar), after clicking one the submenu is displayed. Now I would like to achieve the solution when I press physical Menu button of my device, the same submenu would be displayed.

Comment: This already happens... as long as you are using a standard action bar any items in the overflow are placed in a submenu which is opened when you press the physical menu button

Comment: RSenApps - I know that. But it's not the behaviour I want to achieve. Android by default puts under Menu button only items for which there is no place in the Acton Bar. As my menu has only two items at main level that's not the case. However under one of items at main level I have submenu with 6 options. And here I would like to cover normal button behaviour and to display this submenu when Menu button pressed. I know it's possible as I saw this in one of apps some time ago.

Comment: Still this question is not answered. But I believe it's possible, ex. I noticed sth like this in App Backup&Restore app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup

Comment: I tried to cover onKeyUp and then to run expandActionView() method for the given menu item but it doesn't work (method always returns false which mean that the item hasn't been expanded).